# Pure Hold'Em: Ace high/low rules?

Tags: xbox-one, pure-holdem

Does anyone know the rules in Pure Hold'Em on XB1 regarding how an ace can function as the low card in a straight, I.e. A2345?

I can't find a reference in the in-game docs, and I haven't gotten dealt the right cards to test it. Depending on the pot, I may also be too afraid to test. Anyone tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ace can function as both high and low in straights